# one button active of 5 buttons by data

Tags: javascript

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].onclick = function(){
    if (this.dataset.active == "active") {
      this.dataset.active = "inactive";
    } else {
      this.dataset.active = "active";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.btn[data-active="active"], .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Active Button</h1>
<p>Highlight the active/current (pressed) button.</p>
  
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn" data-active="active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

i want only one button to be active at once having **data-active = "active"** and if changed to **remove the active** from it and be moved to the newly pressed button but my code now makes **everything** active if not and not active if active and i only want one button to be active

like radio box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Created a click event handler on the parent element
- When an element is clicked, check to see if it is a button
- If it is, find the button that is active and if there is one, remove the active attribute
- Then for the one that was clicked, toggle the active data attribute

```js
const header = document.querySelector("#myDIV");

header.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    let activeButton = header.querySelector('.btn[data-active="active"]');
    const currentState = event.target.dataset.active;
    
    if (activeButton && activeButton !== event.target ) {
      activeButton.dataset.active = null;
    }
    
    event.target.dataset.active = currentState === 'active' ? null : 'active';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.btn[data-active="active"], .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Active Button</h1>
<p>Highlight the active/current (pressed) button.</p>
  
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn" data-active="active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Given that only one should have the active attribute on it, the looping is a bit overkill.  Let me update this.  One sec. @JoeDoe

Comment: @JoeDoe There we go.  No looping necessary

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your `onclick` function, you'll want to set each of the buttons to `inactive`. This can be done by creating a *second* loop, as can be seen in the following:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < btns.length; j++) {
      btns[j].dataset.active = "inactive";
    }
    if (this.dataset.active == "active") {
      this.dataset.active = "inactive";
    } else {
      this.dataset.active = "active";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.btn[data-active="active"],
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Active Button</h1>
<p>Highlight the active/current (pressed) button.</p>
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn" data-active="active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

Note that you'll likely also want to make use of `addEventListener()` as opposed to `onclick`, so that your logic is separate from your presentation. This can be seen in the following:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < btns.length; j++) {
      btns[j].dataset.active = "inactive";
    }
    if (this.dataset.active == "active") {
      this.dataset.active = "inactive";
    } else {
      this.dataset.active = "active";
    }
  })
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.btn[data-active="active"],
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Active Button</h1>
<p>Highlight the active/current (pressed) button.</p>
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn" data-active="active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```